# How to calculate confidence interval for correlation coefficient (derived from from covariance)

Tags: correlation, covariance

I have two variables - percent_with_x and percent_with_y across 5 different states as shown below:

```
percent_with_x  
0.44947
0.48601
0.41299
0.43999
0.95145
```

```
percent_with_y
0.48743
0.11818
0.23235
0.83729
0.72262
```

I have a third variable - percent with x and y, defined as the percentage of individuals who had both x and y.

I have calculated the covariance as follows:

$cov = p(x=1, y=1) - p(x)\cdot p(y)$. I calculated this for each state and then took the average as my covariance value.

I am now interested in calculating the confidence interval for my covariance estimate, but unsure how to do this. Any help is appreciated.